# SQLSRV not returning data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sqlsrv

Given a stored procedure on MS SQL Server, if I execute it using SQLSRV and CodeIgniter, I can see that the stored procedure executes and modifies data.

However, if I run a select statement inside the procedure, SQLSRV doesn't return any data. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i need any answer

Comment: @medo there is nowhere near enough info here to give any kind of sensible answer. Would you tell your doctor "I don't feel well" and then let him work the rest out for himself? Or would you tell him where it hurts and how it happened? The same principle applies here.

Comment: For instance, if we could see your PHP code, your stored proc, and the output you're getting currently, we might have a better sense of what's going on. But the links that @RiggsFolly already posted will cover that.

Comment: i have fixed this problem with sql server 2008 but i had it again with the sql server 2014. i will send you a sample of what i have if you do not mind